# Loading image using pick2get by using ng-src

Tags: angularjs, angular2-directives

Our task giving is that try to load images to the shopping application pick2get by using ng-src and make it look attractive.

For which we had written below code -

In HTML file as -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="topnav">
        <a href="#" style="float:right;font-size:20px"><i>Check out</i></a>
        <a href="#" style="float:right; font-size:20px"><i>Sign In</i></a>
        <a href="#/Home" style="float:left; width:150px;" class="active"><b><i>Pick2get</i></b></a>

    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="search_drop_down">
        <select id="month" class="select select-styled">
            <option value="hide">-- Brand --</option>
            <option ng-repeat="pdtBrand in products">{{pdtBrand.brand}}</option>
        </select>

        <select id="year" class="select select-styled">
            <option value="hide">-- Price --</option>
            <option value="low_price_to_high">Low Price to High</option>
            <option value="hign_price_to_low">High Price to Low</option>
        </select>

        <input class="search" placeholder="Search" size="40" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="product_box" ng-repeat="pdt in products">
        <div class="single_1">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="discount">
                    <div class="discount_badge">{{pdt.discount}}</div>
                    <span class="discount_text">Discount</span>
                </div><img ng-src={{pdt.image}}></div></div>
        <div class="single_2">
            <div class="prod_desc">
                <span class="pdt_name">{{pdt.name}}</span>
                <div class="pdt_details_2_col">
                    <span class="brand">Brand</span>
                    <span class="brand_name">{{pdt.brand}}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="pdt_details_2_col">
                    <span class="brand">Price</span>
                    <span class="brand_name">{{pdt.price}}</span>
                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="single_3">
            <div class="quantity_sec">
                <label>Quantity</label>
                <br>
                <input placeholder="Quantity" type="number" ng-model="pdt.quantity">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="single_4">
            <input type="image" src="img/greyCart.png" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48"
                ng-show="pdt.quantity<1?true:false" />
            <input type="image" src="img/orangeCart.png" alt="Submit" width="48" height="48"
                ng-hide="pdt.quantity<1?true:false" ng-click="addToCart();" />
        </div>
    </div>



</body>

</html>
```

In Index JS as

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.quantity=0;
   //Add image property to the products and the image should have the url of images
    var imgPath = 'img/cycle.jpg'
    $scope.products = [
        {
            name : "Happy Cycle",
            discount:"20%",
            price: "2500",
            brand : "Wheels",
            addedToCart:false,
            quantity:0
        },
        {
            name : "Kids Shoes",
            discount:"10%",
            price: "1460",
            brand : "Feel Good",
            addedToCart:false,
            quantity:0
        },
        {
            name : "Polo Baby Care Dress",
            discount:"20%",
            price: "2500",
            brand : "Super Hero",
            addedToCart:false,
            quantity:0
        },
    ]
$scope.addToCart=function(){
    alert('Product Added to Cart successfully')
    return "success";
    }

});
```

Getting error as -

- Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 0 of 1 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
- 1A[2KNode.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1) AngularJS Test Controller should exist product image FAILED
- Expected undefined to equal 'img/cycle.jpg'.at UserContext.<anonymous (test/index_test.js:13:42)
- Node.js (linux; U; rv:v8.15.1): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED)

Please suggest where we went wrong

Comment: need more details .. please share html code from where you are using ng-for loop .. so that we can trace pdt.image

Comment: @Rahul attach full HTML

Comment: but image is not part of the products array you have shared so far

Comment: thanks issue resolved after adding image : 'img/shirt.jpg' in JS file

Answer (score 1):

Product array doesnt have the image key .. it per the html code it should be part of the array

Please add this image file in the array like you have added price other fields..